# Android I need this kind of suggestion list for my own database

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing an application for Urdu Language and I have my own database. I want to show Urdu words like this:

[image: Word Suggestion]

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance..

P.S: I have tried autocomplete text but that works for only a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AutoCompleteTextView, It will accomplish that mission. 
This link will help you 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html